# Connectiont to 2 collections in MongoDB and using express as a route

Tags: mongodb, collections, express

```
//creating a route for http://127.0.0.1:8080/Work
app.get('/Work', function(req, res){

        //connect to my first collection
       db.collection('my-collection1').find().each( function (err,doc) {

            //if there's an error 
             if(err) throw err;

            //if there is no more docs 
            if (!doc) {
                console.dir("No document found");
                return db.close();
                //return;
            }

        //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for x

        });

        //write to the Work.html file in your/views directory  and pass it the variable x
        return res.render('Work', { "x" : x });

        //connect to my 2nd collection
        db.collection('my-collection2').find().each( function (err,doc) {

            //if there's an error 
             if(err) throw err;

            //if there is no more docs 
            if (!doc) {
                console.dir("No document found");
                return db.close();
                //return;
            }

            //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for y

        });

        //write to the Work.html file in your/views directory  and pass it the variable x
        return res.render('Work', { "y" : y });

    });
```

With the above code, What I am tring to do is connect to 2 collections in MongoDB and render them to a webpage file in my /views/ directory using the express framework.

My  html file in my views directory looks like this:

```
<html>
<h6>Hello there.</h6>
<h6>Value of x is:  {{x}} </h6>
<h6>Value of y is: {{y}} </h6>
<html>
```

Now my problem is getting x and y to display. Now this could be due to my lack of understanding of callbacks and asynchronous functions, which I slightly do understand.

Based on what I have provided can someone advise how I would achieve what I want here, whilst also possibly explaining callbacks and asynchronous functions? Maybe my approach is completely wrong tring to connect to 2 collections like this? tks

**Note:** these work on their own(if i dispaly them on there own separate page), here I am trying to bring x and y together and display on the one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that as soon as you call `return res.render('Work', { "x" : x });` your function terminates and the part of your code that calculates `y` is never even executed.

I'm also assuming that you have variables `x` and `y` declared above the scope of your `GET` function somewhere that you're storing the values in? If not, you should do that to make their scope more explicit.

You're also calling `db.close()`, which isn't really necessary since you're staying in the same db and just switching collections, so from a performance perspective you want to simply keep using the same connection for both calculations (connection pooling will take place under the hood).

**Async explanation of what your code is doing:**

With those issues out of the way, the asynchronous nature of the calls means that both your functions (the one that calculates x and the one that calculates y) are executed in parallel (ie at the same time), and since you don't know which which complete first you could be making a call to `res.render` without both `x` and `y`. The `render` function can only be called once in Express because upon being called it will send the results back to the user's browser and a `200 OK` HTTP response and end their connection to your Node webserver.

**So your basic problem boils down to the need to guarantee that BOTH `x` and `y` have finished being calculated, and then sending only ONE response back to the web browser.**

You have two choices to deal with this:

1. Turn them into serial function calls - ie call the function that calculates `x`, wait for it to finish, and only then call the function that calculates `y`, and then render the results. This is where callbacks come in. Note that this approach could be slower than doing both calculations in an async fashion since you're forcing the second step to wait for what could be a time-consuming process to complete before it can even start.
2. Run both calculations asynchronously, and when either terminates it can check to see if the other one has also finished. Whichever one finishes second will make a call to `return res.render('Work', { "x" : x, "y" : y });` with the knowledge that both `x` and `y` have been populated with your desired results. You need to perform it this wat

**Option 1** looks something like this with callbacks (notice that the calculation for `y` is only initiated once there are no more documents to process to calculate `x`):

```
//creating a route for http://127.0.0.1:8080/Work
app.get('/Work', function(req, res){

    //connect to my first collection
    db.collection('my-collection1').find().each( function (err,doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for x

        //once there are no more docs, initiate the calculation for y
        if (!doc) {
            console.dir("No document found");

            db.collection('my-collection2').find().each( function (err,doc) {
                if(err) throw err;

                //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for y

                //if there is no more docs, then we know that both x and y have been calculated
                if (!doc) {
                    console.dir("No document found");
                    res.render('Work', { "x" : x, "y" : y });
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

There's also a variety of framework to allow you to chain async calls in a synchronous fashion in Node - check out [streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs), which allows you do chain methods a little more cleanly using the underscore character as your callback, but even if you use such a library it's pretty much translating into what my code above is doing under the hood.

**Option 2** (my preferred option since it's probably better performance) simply checks to see if the calculation for both `x` and `y` has finished by checking a counter:

```
//creating a route for http://127.0.0.1:8080/Work
app.get('/Work', function(req, res){

    var counter = 0;

    //connect to my first collection
    db.collection('my-collection1').find().each( function (err,doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for x

        //once there are no more docs, add one to the counter
        if (!doc) {
            console.dir("No document found");
            counter++;

            if (counter == 2) {
                res.render('Work', { "x" : x, "y" : y });
            }
        }
    });

    db.collection('my-collection2').find().each( function (err,doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        //...do stuff here to your docs here to get a value for x

        //once there are no more docs, add one to the counter
        if (!doc) {
            console.dir("No document found");
            counter++;

            if (counter == 2) {
                res.render('Work', { "x" : x, "y" : y });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

So basically, you execute both calculations in parallel and whichever finishes second will call `res.render` and send the response back.

Note that I didn't actually test out the above code snippets, but they should give you the idea.